# How do I pass in a list of arguments to subprocess.run?(python)

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a simple def stored in C:/Users/admin/Desktop/sample.py,

```
import time, os

def cook(sec):
    print('cooking started')
    time.sleep(sec)
    print(f'cooking done in {sec} sec(s) on process: {os.getpid()}')
```

My goal is to use subprocess library to run sample.py, I use anaconda as my interpreter

```
import subprocess
path = 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe C:/Users/admin/Desktop/sample.py'
subprocess.run(path, shell=True)
```

How can I pass in a list of args to subprocess.run?
I tried to join path with a list [cook(1), cook(2), cook(3)].failed. What shall I do?
Ideally, pass in a list and run the def one by one.
Appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `subpocess` to call a Python function. Have your program `import sample` and then call its main function.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Actually that's what I suggested to my leader. Leader said NO. We have to use subprocess to call the py file. Any idea how I shall achieve this?

Comment: Start by using Windows \ path delimiters instead of /. Put `r` before the opening quote of the string ?so you don't have to escape them: `r'C:\...` Put the parameters in the string after `sample.py`. Test the resulting string manually at the console before asking `subprocess` to run it for you. You get more useful error messages that way.

Comment: You can pass parameters like this: subprocess.run(["/path/to/python.exe", "/path/to/sample.py", "--parameter1 1234", "--parameter2 asd"]), but you have to modify your sample.py to accept arguments, See https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html

Comment: This is what I get from termianl, CompletedProcess(args='C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe C:/Users/admin/Desktop/sample.py "--parameter1"', returncode=0) Did it run?

Comment: Sorry, I tried again. subprocess.run(["/path/to/python.exe", "/path/to/sample.py", "--parameter1 1234", "--parameter2 asd"]) does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example:

```
subprocess.run(["/path/to/python.exe", "/path/to/sample.py", "2", "3", "4"])
```

Your sample.py

```
import time
import os
import sys


def cook(sec):
    print('cooking started')
    time.sleep(sec)
    print(f'cooking done in {sec} sec(s) on process: {os.getpid()}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # See argparser module, this is just a simple example without using argparser
    # Argument 0 is always the name of your file
    # Argument 1 is the number of cookings
    # Argument 2 and beyond are the seconds for those cookings
    numberOfCookings = int(sys.argv[1])
    for i in range(numberOfCookings):
        cook(int(sys.argv[2+i]))
```

Comment: I tweaked your solution a little bit. 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    numberOfCookings = len(sys.argv)
    for i in range(1, numberOfCookings):
        cook(int(sys.argv[i]))

com = ["C:/path/to/python.exe", "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/sample.py", "2", "4", "6"] 
subprocess.run(com, shell=True)
It will run three times with parameters2,4, and 6

Comment: I'm glad to help you, I like the way you tweaked it :)

Comment: I tested it again, my code has a major bug. It keeps running, infinite loop! How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you open a new post and describe the problem your facing. And send me a link to that post

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is the thing, we decided to import the function, problem solved.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear that :)